# How to make a list into a tree structure in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

From the following php script:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $category = $row["category"];
    $thing = $row["thing"];
    echo $category." ".$thing;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I echo the following lines:

```
Book book1
Book book2
Chair chair1
Chair chair2
Table table1
```

but I would like to display as the following result :

```
Book 
    book1
    book2

Chair
    chair1
    chair2

Table
    table1
```

I know I have to make a simple loop somewhere here but I don't get the result I want.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Bonus : I am planning on make all these words clickable to get the them in a variable. If you could insert this tip into your answer it would be nice.

EDIT :

Here is what I tried so far (trying to add also an icon):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{   
    foreach($row as $item) 
    {
        echo "<div style='padding-right: 5px' class='glyphicon glyphicon-book'></div>";
        echo $item;
        echo "<div style='padding-left: 20px'>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<br>";
    }   
}
```

Comment: It need not be recursive. This can be done in one loop. Have you tried anything? You mentioned a recursive way you tried, but I see no code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224738/discussion-between-getset-and-pozinux).

Comment: @getSet Chatting with you made me understand how I can improve my next questions on SO and what was missing so that It does'nt feel like I didn't search a minimum by myself and that I just ask for "free code". I will strive to post better quality questions next time. Big thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{   
    if ( !isset( $table[ $row["category"] ] ) ) {
    
        // No category exists, create now
        $table[ $row["category"] ] = array();
    }
    
    // append to category
    $table[ $row["category"] ][] = $row["thing"];
} 
    
// some additional sorting here 
/* todo */

print_r($table);
```

This solution piggybacks off of PHP inherent named keys by "strings" (which behind the scenes are hashed into "buckets". Since your data only shows a data structure that nests one level deep, it is not a recursive solution. But even still, your basic requirement is on category, so will work even if you have a nested data structure.

`isset` will check if the category exists. If not a new sub array is created which will hold those values.

`[]` syntax is PHP style to append to an array.

Comment: I mentioned in chat (deleted comments) how when u show no code, your exact solution will differ. However I did solve the "tree" structure. Credit me at this point and we can talk about further "problems".

Comment: I posted what I came up with. Thanks for encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GetSet answer, I could create the right multidimensional array I needed to get the foloowing result:

```
Array ( [Book] => Array ( [0] => book1 [1] => book2 ) [Chair] => Array ( [0] => chair1 [1] => chair2 ) [Table] => Array ( [0] => table1 ) )
```

I wanted then to display on a html page like that:

```
Book 
    book1
    book2

Chair
    chair1
    chair2

Table
    table1
```

After reading more about PHP arrays, I made out this solution which seem working for me (with the icones):

```
foreach ($table as $key => $value) 
{
    echo "<div style='padding-right: 5px; font-size:13px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-book'></div>";
    echo $key;
    echo "<div style='height: 2px'></div>";
    foreach ($value as $v2) 
    {
        echo "<div style='padding-right: 7px;padding-left: 15px; font-size:11px;' class='fa fa-file-text-o'></div>";
        echo $v2;
        echo "<div style='height: 5px'></div>";
    }
    echo "<div style='height: 10px'></div>";
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I know have to work on making clickable these words.
Also, I would love to be able to reduce one category by clicking on the book icon but I imagine I have to use JavaScript for that and I don't really know this language.